# Python: method to remove all duplicate points from a X,Y,Z file that have identical x and y coordinates

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matplotlib

I am looking a method to removes all duplicate points from a a X,Y,Z file. What i wish to code is remove points that have identical x and y coordinates. The first point survives, all subsequent duplicates are removed.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.mlab as ml
import matplotlib.delaunay
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata

# my area boundary box
xmax, xmin, ymax, ymin = 640000.06, 636999.83, 6070000.3, 6066999.86

# generate fake data
ndata = 500000
# Generate random data to simulate
x = np.random.randint(xmin, xmax, ndata)
y = np.random.randint(ymin, ymax, ndata)
z = np.random.randint(0,20,ndata)
mypoints = zip(x,y,z)
```

Thanks in advance for helps and tips!!!
:)

Comment: You've shown us how you generated these points, but not what you've tried to do to filter them.

Comment: Please, change your answer selection.  I didn't notice you were using `numpy` so my examples are not the optimal solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run Python 2.7 or higher, you could use an `OrderedDict` as a filter:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

tmp = OrderedDict()
for point in zip(x, y, z):
    tmp.setdefault(point[:2], point)

mypoints = tmp.values()
```

Apart from filtering, this also preserves the order of the random sequences.

---

Another receipie can be found [at the Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7.3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby), which can be translated to something like:

```
from itertools import groupby

keyfunc = lambda p: p[:2]
mypoints = []
for k, g in groupby(sorted(zip(x, y, z), key=keyfunc), keyfunc):
    mypoints.append(list(g)[0])
```

Comment: Just to point out, I came up with the second solution after reading @Mark_Ransom's comment about the stable sort.

Comment: -1 as you shouldn't advice loops for numpy arrays without telling the OP, that normally vectorized functions and indexing would be the way to work with numpy arrays.

Comment: Sure, I didn't notice the `import numpy` line.  I'll delete the answer as soon as the OP selects yours.

Comment: it would be enough, if you would update your answer. however there are some more lines containing `numpy` ;-)

Answer (score 5):

As you are asking for help and tips:

the first thing I would suggest is, that you should avoid looping over numpy arrays, as this is inefficient and numpy arrays are not designed for that. If you are working with numpy array you should use vectorized numpy functions and indexing to sort your points and remove the duplicates.

[Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) (which is build on top of numpy) `DataFrames` have a built in `drop_duplicates` method which should be faster than getting your points by looping over the array as proposed by C2H5OH.

You can compare them using `ipython`:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict
from itertools import groupby 

def with_ordered_dict(x, y, z):        
    tmp = OrderedDict()
    for point in zip(x, y, z):
        tmp.setdefault(point[:2], point)
    return tmp.values()

def with_groupby(x, y, z):        
    keyfunc = lambda p: p[:2]
    mypoints = []                             
    for k, g in groupby(sorted(zip(x, y, z), key=keyfunc), keyfunc):
        mypoints.append(list(g)[0])
    return mypoints

def with_dataframe(x, y, z):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x':x, 'y':y, 'z':z})
    return df.drop_duplicates(cols=['x', 'y'])

In [140]: %timeit mypoints = with_ordered_dict(x, y, z)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.47 s per loop

In [141]: %timeit mypoints = with_groupby(x, y, z)
1 loops, best of 3: 4.22 s per loop

In [142]: %timeit mypoints = with_dataframe(x, y, z)
1 loops, best of 3: 713 ms per loop
```

So with 500000 data points pandas is three or four times faster than with `OrderedDict` and about six times faster than with `groupby`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to sort these points and detect points with the same X and Y. Sort by X, then Y or vice versa.

Comment: You can sort by both X and Y at the same time by making a tuple of them. This works because `sort` is stable, any elements with identical keys will keep their original order.

Answer (score 0):

just a small change from code proposed by """C2H5OH""" in order to avoid the print on video

```
from collections import 
from collections import OrderedDict
for point in zip(x, y, z):
... a = tmp.setdefault(point[:2], point)
... 
mypoints = tmp.values()
```

Comment: You saw the returnin value of `tmp.setdefault(...)` because you ran the code interactively.  When you run it normally, you will not see anything printed.